# Use Xcode from a Remote machine

Tags: xcode, ssh, xcodebuild

I'm working on a iPhone application in a team but one of us doesn't have a Mac so he can't run Xcode (he has a linux machine). 
Right now, he working on his part of the code and time to time, he comes on our machines to test his code. This work method is annoying for all of us.

My goal is to give him a ssh access to our machines so he can use Xcode remotely.

I've read question about almost the same topic, but the only useful info I've found was the command `xcodebuild` that let you compile a xcode project using the CLI.

What about running the code on a connected provisioned device and get the console log over ssh ?

I'm not interested about running the code on the simulator since our linux teammate is working on assembly code dedicated to the arm processor.

Answer (score 1):

When you account for the drop in productivity, isn’t it *much* easier to get him an older Mac Mini?

Comment: You're right ! Increasing Productivity wasn't actually our main goal. (EDITED Question).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe VNC to give the developer GUI access when required?

It may be cheaper and easier to give him a MacMini of course.